# SSRS Export to Excel Filter To Many Tabs

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssrs-2012

I am currently using MS Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

In my SSRS report, I currently have a table with 4 columns in it with 7 records like so:

```
 ID FirstName LastNameInitial Department
 1  Joe        S              Management
 2  Sally      T              Management
 3  Kyle       V              Employee
 4  Sandra     B              Employee
 5  Nick       N              Management
 6  Jess       A              Management
 7  Priya      S              Employee
```

I want to make it so that when a user exports from SSRS to Excel, that I can have 2 separate tabs (Management, Employee) that the records will filter to.

For example, ID's #1,2,5,6 would go underneath Management Tab. And the others would go underneath Employee Tab.

Can someone help me with how to do this? Or maybe suggest an easier way to go about this?

Comment: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/762/ssrs-r2-naming-excel-worksheet-tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can offer is to:
Add a parent group, and group by Department.
Right click on the new group and add a page break between each instance of a group. (This will now mean that Management and Employee will be shown on separate pages).
Delete the new parent column, making sure to choose delete columns only.
When you export you will now have multiple tabs.
Use the demo provided in the comment above to set the tab names automatically http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/762/ssrs-r2-naming-excel-worksheet-tabs

Answer (score 0):

Used a list, placed my table inside it and then grouped on the particular column I needed to group by.